# Decision tree classifier with list of 2d coordinates + categorical value

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have a numpy array with features and labels.

Each datapoint consists of 10 2d coordinates (x,y) and a string which indicates the orientation ('left' or 'right').

Example:

```
[array([[-19.24181754,  -0.6933614 ],
       [-17.39631579,  -0.84320702],
       [-14.57501754,  12.99707368],
       [ -8.6202386 ,   4.90138246],
       [  0.82478596,  20.01929825],
       [  4.79946667, -10.70312982],
       [  7.10694035,  17.47812632],
       [ 11.06254737,  14.17312982],
       [ 17.04467368,   0.19169825],
       [ 18.94181053,   6.92687018]])
  'left']]
```

Labels are 12 different strings (`'4-4-2', '5-3-2', ...`). I want to try different algorithms with this data to compare how well they perform. The first algorithm is a decision tree classifier.

I see two potential problems:

1. array of 10 points as a feature
2. categorical data

For the second point, one-hot-coding should solve the problem. Is there a very simple way to do this within the numpy array?

For the first point, I'm not sure if it is even a problem since I didn't try it so far.

EDIT:

My coding:

```
#Separate features and labels
X = test[:, [0, 4]]
Y = test[:,10]

zeros = np.zeros((len(X), 2), dtype=int)

X = np.append(X, zeros, axis=1)

for datapoint in X:
    if(datapoint[1] == 'left'):
        datapoint[2] = 1
    else:
        datapoint[3] = 1

X = np.delete(X, 1, 1)

#Divide into test and training data: 80% training, 20% test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=100)

#Initialize classifier
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state = 100,
                               max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)

#Train classifier
clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/D071947/PycharmProjects/Formation/DecisionTree.py", line 41, in <module>
    clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\D071947\PycharmProjects\Formation\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 790, in fit
    X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
  File "C:\Users\D071947\PycharmProjects\Formation\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 116, in fit
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
  File "C:\Users\D071947\PycharmProjects\Formation\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I guess it has something to do with the array of 2d coordinates?

Comment: You can just represent your 10-d array of 2D features as 20 features.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was indeed the nested array of coordinates. Like suggested by cardelling representing the 10 2d coordinates as 20 features worked.

To flatten the list I used `numpy.ravel()`